# Grails Query with bi-directional hasMany association

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, grails, grails-orm

Suppose, I have two class named User and Authority.

The specification of those two classes are:

```
User{
  Integer id;
  String userCode;
  String password;
  boolean active;

  static hasMany = [authorities : Authority, userGroups : UserGroup]

  static mapping = {
        table("security_user")
    }
}


Authority{
    Integer id
    String roleTitle
    String description

    static hasMany = [features : Feature, users : User]

    static belongsTo = User;


}
```

In the Query level how can I get all the authorities those are mapped with one particular object of User?

Like, I have tried in the following approach:

```
user = User.findByUserCodeAndPassword(userCode,password);
Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
users.add(user);

List<Authority> authority = Authority.findAllByUsers(users);
```

But the above code is giving runtime grails exception. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `user.authorities` no need to do all these things after getting user object.